# C++ associative container with two search criteria

Tags: c++, boost, stl, associative-array

I am looking for a container for storing my objects of a class, called Link, which has a member variable: "std::string linkID". the size of container can be as high as several milions, therefore fast look up is more preferred.
1-Later I need to look up the container using linkID
2-but, due to some reasons, the order in which the objects are added is also important.

I have gone through vector,list,set,map... and I am going to study muliset, multimap and boost multi index. But I guess,being new to C++, I still need some more experienced opinion to help me choose the best container based on the above two criteria.

Thank you
vahid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me this looks as a perfekt usecase for boost::multi_index_container

your type declaration should look similat to this (not tested)

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    Link,
    indexed_by<
        sequenced<>,
        ordered_unique< member< Link, std::string, &Link::linkID> >,
        ordered_unique< member< Link, std::string, &Link::linkID_2 > >
    >
> LinkList;
LinkList s;
s.push_back(Link(...));
```

It is in general the same as the solution posted by Frerich Raabe. But I think with less pitfalls and likely more optimized.
Read the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) on the boost page to learn how to access the elements stored in s.

Your comment...

> Actually, I am developing an already existing project where in, they
> have used std::vector for only STORING the elements(as you pointed
> out). so now can I use the 'storage' vector as is and just add the
> maps as you suggested?

This is not possible. Vector iterators stay not valid. They can become undefined when you add or remove elements to the vector.

Comment: thanx, i will test this tomorrow and will post the result

Comment: Hi Smittii, I hope you are still following this. Picking up boost took some time from me so I am trying your solution today.OK, about your code snippet above, I want to make sure if I am getting it correctly: 1-the "sequenced<>" part will help me iterate through Link objects in order of their insertion, and 2-"ordered_unique< member< Link, std::string, &Link::linkID> >" will help me access the objects in ascending order of Link::linkID. Are BOTH of the  statements true? if yes, this is my exact solution.otherwise,how should I modify the code to have the both conditions hold true?tanx

Comment: I don't know axactly what you mean with "true statement". The container works just as you described. You can access the elements by all mechanisems you define in the indexed_by template.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds perfect to use [Boost Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html).

Comment: I looked at the link you sent. well, I know i mentioned order and linkID as my lookup criteria. so defining boost::bimap< std::string, int > (left value for Link.linkID and right value for order), 1-where will the actual object(Link*) will be stored?  2-I am not going to keep a counter to used it when populating the second value of the pair. I need something like vector's push_back for that part. Any Idea how I can do this using bimap>

Answer (score 1):

If the properties by which you want to look up links don't change very often, you could choose a `std::list<Link>` as your primary container to hold the link objects. Then, for each criterion, you have one `std::map` which maps a value to an iterator pointing into the list. E.g.

```
typedef std::list<Link> LinkList;

LinkList links = ...;
std::map<std::string, LinkList::iterator> linkByName;
std::map<unsigned int, LinkList::iterator> linkByPopularity;
```

The nice thing about a `std::list` is that it has very strong iterator invalidation guarantees (basically, your iterator into a list only becomes invalid if you remove the element from the list).

In order to have these structures updated consistently, you could wrap this all into a 'LinkCollection' wrapper or so.

Comment: isn't std::list slow, as compared to std::set? if yes, can I just replace std::list with std::set in your example?

Comment: @rahman: The idea is that the `std::list` is only used for storing elements, not for accessing them. You then use other containers which hold iterators into the list for actually accessing elements. So if you need a quick way to access elements by index, you could have a `std::vector<LinkList::iterator>`.

Comment: :Got it. you made a good point that made me ask another simple question that can solve my problem in a much better way.Actually, I am developing an already existing project where in, they have used std::vector for only STORING the elements(as you pointed out). so now can I use the 'storage' vector as is and just add the maps as you suggested? this way I will gladly improve the performance without undergoing the burden of replacing that vector with list.

Comment: @rahman: The issue with using a `std::vector` for storing the objects is that iterators pointing into a vector quickly become invalidated (for instance, the vector may invalidate all iterators if elements are added to the vector, or it invalidates all iterators beyond some element which you're removing). That's why having a `std::list` for storage is convenient.

Comment: thanks for the help. I will post the result later. someone else recommended multi-index from boost being similar to your solution. any comments